# roswtf says rosinstall missing

Tags: ros, rosinstall, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started to go through the ROS tutorials and I reached roswtf. Now it says that it cant find the rosinstall python module, but it is installed. Not sure if I ever going to need rosinstall, but right now this warning just bothers me. Is it possible to know why roswtf says there is a problem? Or can I suppress the warning?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro.

```
viki@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/devel$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: rosinstall -- 

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [htp://localhost:11311]
```

.

```
viki@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/devel$ dpkg --get-selections | grep rosinstall
python-rosinstall               install

viki@ubuntu:~$ which rosinstall 
/usr/local/bin/rosinstall
```

I even tried apt-get reinstall and purge remove and install, but no avail.

I installed rosinstall_shellcompletion with pip, maybe that caused some nasty stuff under the roof.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149706/roswtf-says-rosinstall-missing/) by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can fix this by running

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

But unless you need rosinstall, it shouldn't be a problem.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on 2014-04-08**:
Sorry I didnt made it more visible, but at the end of the code you can see that "dpkg --get-selections | grep rosinstall" returned with python-rosinstall installed.
And apt-get install returns that "python-rosinstall is already the newest version."

**Comment by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on 2014-04-08**:
Just to be sure I did a "sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-rosinstall" but the problem still stands.
I even tried
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-rosinstall
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall

But roswtf still thinks its missing.

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-04-08**:
Oops, missed that. If you run "which rosinstall" does it actually exist?

**Comment by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on 2014-04-08**:
It says
/usr/local/bin/rosinstall

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-08**:
It sounds like you have rosinstall installed through pip; try running `sudo pip uninstall rosinstall` REPREATEDLY until it tells you that rosinstall is not installed.

**Comment by [NLZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/14511/nlz/) on 2014-04-08**:
I installed rosinstall_shellcompletion with pip, but pip uninstalling both (after apt-get remove) and reinstalling rosinstall with apt-get did not changed the error.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-04-10**:
That's weird. If you installed rosinstall correctly (using apt-get), it should be in /usr/bin, not /usr/local/bin.